# Does selenium 2.0 supports dynamic string value for By.xpath

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on checkbox using following code:

String podID = "'microsoft-gallery-clipbox-pod-" + podId.substring(3)+"'";

```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("id(" + podID + ")")).click();
```

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"id('microsoft-gallery-clipbox-pod-15423100')"}
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.vers

When i run following code it works fine:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('microsoft-gallery-clipbox-pod-15424100')")).click();

Any idea why the first code doesnt works?

Answer (score 0):

The two IDs you show are not identical (the numbers at the end are different):

```
microsoft-gallery-clipbox-pod-15423100

microsoft-gallery-clipbox-pod-15424100
```

Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the following:

```
String podID = "microsoft-gallery-clipbox-pod-" + podId.substring(3); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='" + podID + "']")).click();
```